# Executing multiple Pyspark scripts in parallel

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

How can I initiate execution of multiple Pyspark scripts from one notebook, in parallel?

Note: I'm currently using Azure's Databricks(enterprize edition)